# Iterating back folders to find wp-config.php

Tags: php, directory, constants

I have a php script which is executed outside the scope of Wordpress, however I need to use a Wordpress-constant defined in `wp-config.php`. I want to make the script platform indenpendant.

My script is in subfolders (a theme) and I'm trying to iterate back to find wp-config. My theme files should be able to be placed in different deps (sub-folders) preferably!

I cant get the statement in my while-loop to run one single lap though, and I can't understand why! I'm trying set the condition so that it will stop in system root like (c:)

```
function getWPConfig() {
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
    $dir = addslashes($dir);    
    while ($pos = strpos($dir, "\\") !== false) { //&& strpos($dir, (string)DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) > 1
        $wpConfig = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'wp-config.php';
        if (file_exists($wpConfig)) {
            echo 'Found wp-config: '. $wpConfig;
            return $wpConfig;
        } else {
            'Could not find: '. $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'wp-config.php';
        }
        $tempDir = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $dir);
        $end = end($tempDir);
        $dir = str_replace($end, '', $tempDir);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: You could use `dirname()` to traverse up the directory tree. Easier than cutting it your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @Pekka's suggestion I wrote this function instead! :-)

```
function getWPConfig() {
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
    $lastDir = __FILE__;
    while (strlen($dir) < strlen($lastDir)) {
        $wpConfig = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'wp-config.php';
        if (file_exists($wpConfig)) {   
            return $wpConfig;
        }
        $lastDir = $dir;
        $dir = dirname($dir);
    }
    return;
}
```